# Bootloader smashed

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, bootloader

Yesterday i got a friend to burn a disk with the "try out/install" package of Ubuntu.

My problem is following:

Tried to install Ubuntu on another partition then the one i got windows installed on. This resulted in that my bootloader now is completely smashed and i cannot boot any of my OS's.

Right now i am trying to install Ubuntu once again using the exact same DVD but it always seem just to stand endlessly on the install step. Nothing ever happens. Had it stand all night long and when i woke up it wall still installing.

Anyone knows how to resolve this problem and actually get Ubuntu on my PC?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: search in AskUbuntu for MBR repair using Live CD and follow the detailled instructions

Comment: CAnnot seem to find a search function here so i tried google. Couldn't really find anything that wasn't too advanced or out of my league. Got another suggestion?

Comment: The installer program could be waiting for some input from you. You will see an indication that the install is taking place but things are only being put into system memory as a means of speeding up the install process, while you are putting in user information. At some point the install stops. That is when you need to confirm to actually install and make changes to the hard disk.

Comment: Incorrect in this case, the pc stood up all night installing and there was no progress bar or user input at all in the progress.

Tried it once more and everytime i try to install either ubuntu or windows my hard drive does not show up. It just vanished.

If i just start the pc normaly it start booting windows 7 but as it loads i get blue screen of death and if i try to use the repair tool it gives me an access denied message to some devices.

I am more then confused now. Been trying to fix it all day. I am desperate to get it fixed. Thank you for you're try :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is an option for somebody with minimal knowledge - no offense -:

If you have an USB stick (4 GB) install ubuntu on the stick using the live DVD. Then boot and change the boot order to usb (for HP by presing F9; or change it in the bios). At start up you will see the grub bootmenu:
Top entry the ubuntu on the stick
second entry ubuntu on the HD
Third entry windows
choose ubuntu on the HD open the terminal and type "sudo update-grub", enter your passowrd. Now restart the computer but this from the HD and normally GRUB should greet you.